# For a directory, rename a file in a sub-directory with the sub-directory name+old filename into a new directory

Tags: python

I have a folder with multiple sub-folders each with a file inside. I'm working in python and would like to rename the file with ***the associated sub-folder name plus the old file name to become new filename***.

I've been able to get a list of the sub-folder and file names with `os.walk()` but I'm having problems changing the filename.

```
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
            os.rename(name, r)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: rename: dst should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not
>   list

When I return r I get the root and file name but am not able to change the filename. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a similar answer to @VkreddyKomatireddy's, but it uses `listdir()` at both levels, and it checks for and ignores more deeply nested directories in the first level of subdirectories.

Here's my code, well annotated:

```
import os

def collapse_dirs(dir):

    # get a list of elements in the target directory
    elems = os.listdir(dir)

    # iterate over each element
    for elem in elems:

        # compute the path to the element
        path = os.path.join(dir, elem)

        # is it a directory?  If so, process it...
        if os.path.isdir(path):

            # get all of the elements in the subdirectory
            subelems = os.listdir(path)

            # process each entry in this subdirectory...
            for subelem in subelems:

                # compute the full path to the element
                filepath = os.path.join(path, subelem)

                # we only want to proceed if the element is a file.  If so...
                if os.path.isfile(filepath):

                    # compute the new path for the file - I chose to separate the names with an underscore,
                    # but this line can easily be changed to use whatever separator you want (or none)
                    newpath = os.path.join(path, elem + '_' + subelem)

                    # rename the file
                    os.rename(filepath, newpath)

def main():
    collapse_dirs('/tmp/filerename2')

main()
```

Here's my target directory before running the code:

```
filerename2
├── a
│   └── xxx.txt
├── b
│   ├── xxx.txt
│   └── yyyy
│       └── zzzz
├── c
│   └── xxx.txt
└── xxxx
```

and here it is after:

```
filerename2
├── a
│   └── a_xxx.txt
├── b
│   ├── b_xxx.txt
│   └── yyyy
│       └── zzzz
├── c
│   └── c_xxx.txt
└── xxxx
```

Comment: This worked as I needed. Thank you and the documentation was appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could be of help.  I just noticed that one of my comments was wrong, and fixed it...the bit about exactly one file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
def list_files(dir):
    sub_folders = os.listdir(dir)
    for sub_folder in sub_folders:
        sub_folder_path = os.path.join(dir,sub_folder)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sub_folder_path):
            for file in files:
                new_filename = root.replace(dir, "").replace(os.path.sep,"_").strip("_")+"_" + file
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, new_filename))
input_dir = ""
assert os.path.isdir(input_dir),"Enter a valid directory path which consists of sub-directories"
list_files(input_dir)
```

This will do the job for multiple sub-directories not nested directories. If you want to change how the name of the file should be, change the line `new_filename = sub_folder+ "" + file`.

Comment: You code looks good.  I gave it an upvote.  Note that it fails, however, if there are directories in the top level directories that contain files.  I think this is because walk will try to go down more levels, but something isn't quite right when it does that.

Comment: Thank you Vkreddy, this worked, but for some reason put the directory name twice in the new file name. I'm still trying to work out why this is the case.

Comment: Updated the code with the fixes mentioned by @Steve. Thank you!